# tensorflowをdjangoで用いる際に、一度構築、ロードしたモデルをアプリ起動中にずっと使えるようにしたいです。

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

django中でtensorflowを使っているwebアプリケーションを作っているのですが、入力されてきたデータに対して学習済みモデルがforward処理を実行をするとき、毎回モデルの構築と学習済みパラメータのロードを行なっているため、処理に時間がかかってしまいます。可能ならば、アプリケーションが立ち上がった時にモデルの構築と学習済みパラメータのロードを行い、forward処理を実行する時に毎回モデル構築を行わないようにしたいです。下に私の簡易的なコードを記述します。ちなみに、djangoのviews.pyで自分で定義した処理を行う関数をimportしています。

views.py

```
from main import main #it is the function that deal the image data

class Example(Formview):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        image = form.data
        output = main(image)
        return JsonResponse(output)
```

main.py

```
def main(input):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():

        with tf.Session() as sess:

            # load model and parameters
            net.load_model(model)
            # deal the image data
            output = net(input)

            return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Django起動時に一度だけ処理を実行したいと言うことであれば、`AppConfig.ready()`メソッドをオーバーライドすればいいようです（バージョン1.7以降）。それ以前のバージョンでの対応方法などについての詳細は、次のページが参考になると思います。

[Execute code when Django starts ONCE only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791911/execute-code-when-django-starts-once-only)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記のアドバイスからAppConfig.ready()で、Sessionをwithで開くのでなく、sess = Session()　などインスタンスとして取っておくことで、アプリを一度起動すれば、いつでもpredict できるようになりました。その代わりに、メモリの使用量多くなりますが。